# How can I get VMWare Fusion 4.0 to work on Mountain Lion?

Tags: vmware, macos

After upgrading to Mountain Lion, I find that when I attempt to launch VMWare Fusion 4.0 I receive the error:

**You can't use this version of the application "VMWare Fusion" with this version of OS X**

Has anyone found any workarounds for this? Should I migrate to Parallels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of VMWare Fusion, in your situation you will need manually download it as indicated below for the situation you describe in your question:

> **I upgraded to Mountain Lion and now VMware Fusion 4 won’t start. What happened?**
>
> Mountain Lion appears to detect some older versions of VMware Fusion 4 and prevent them from launching. To resolve this issue, login to http://my.vmware.com/ (free product registration required) and download VMware Fusion 4.1.3. It can be found under “Products & Downloads > All Downloads > VMware Fusion”

According to [VMware Fusion and OS X Mountain Lion FAQ](http://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2012/07/vmware-fusion-and-os-x-mountain-lion-faq.html)

Comment: Meh, and 3 will never work. VMWare *did* have an upgrade campaign with reduced price not too long ago, but they failed to say "btw, 3 won't work on ML so better give us $ (rather than $$)" :-(

Comment: Where you running a trial version of VMWare 4?

Comment: @MrDaniel Didn't get your question. I am running 3.1. VMWare had offered discount on upgrading to 4, which I didn't buy, but would've bought in a breeze if I had known that 3.x won't work on ML (which is stated in the FAQ you posted to).